# How to format string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, format

I want to format string in Javascript. With formatting, I mean:

- Deleting *whitespaces or tabs in the beginning and end* of string.
- Deleting *multiple whitespaces* between words in string.
- Making commas in "sequence"

I know I can achieve this with `regex`, but couldn't figure out how.

Now:

```js
var myString = "     Hello  , how are         you   ? ";
```

How I need after:

```js
myString = "Hello, how are you?";
```

I tried this:

```js
var myString = "     Hello  , how are         you   ? ";
myString.replace(/^\s*|\s{2,}|\s$/, '');
console.log(myString);
```

But I'm getting:

```
Hello, how areyou?
```

If you know please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: just use trim() instead of regex like here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may produce the desired string by replacing matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.

```
^[ \t]*|[ \t](?=[ \t,?])|[ \t]*$
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/ixSb4Z/3/)

Javascript's regular engine performs the following following operations.

```
^            : match beginning of string
[ \t]*       : match 0+ spaces or tabs
|            : or
[ \t]        : match a space or tab
(?=[ \t,?])  : next character must be a space, tab, comma or question mark
|            : or
[ \t]*       : match 0+ spaces or tabs
$            : match end of string
```

`(?=[ \t,?])` is a *positive lookahead*.

I have assumed that, as in the example, all spaces and tabs preceding question marks (as well as commas) are to be removed. If spaces and tabs preceding other characters should be removed as well, those characters should be added to the character class `[ \t,?]`. We might write, for example, `[ \t,?.!:;]`.

The special character `\s`, which matches all whitespace characters, should *not* be used in place of `[ \t]`. That is because `\s` also matches newlines. If for example, the string were     `abc  \n   x`   , using `\s` would result in the string `abcx`, whereas using `[ \t]` would convert the string to `abc\nx`.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved your problem with 3 regular expressions, but the first is done by the already existing `String.trim()` method of JavaScript.

```js
var myString = "     Hello  , how are         you   ? ";
myString = myString
.trim() // trim start and end
.replace(/[ \t\n]+/g, ' ') // reduce whitespace to one space
.replace(/ ([,\?\.\!\;])/g, '$1'); // remove one space before pointation characters
console.log(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myString = "     Hello  , how are         you   ? ";

myString = myString.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
myString = myString.replace(/ [ ,]/g, ',');
myString = myString.replace(/ [ !]/g, '!');
myString = myString.replace(/ [ ?]/g, '?');
myString = myString.replace(/ [ .]/g, '.');
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = myString.trim();
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Comment: **Pro-Tip:** Never use `innerHTML` for non-HTML and unescaped brackets text. Use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) instead.

Comment: Another tip: Use @<Name> in the comments (e.g. @NiklasE.), to get the addressed person notified. Otherwise you must hope they stumble across your response. StackOverflow automatically gives you suggestions when you tip in @. Post owners get notified by default.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go with a single regex:

```js
var myString = "     Hello  , how are         you   ? ";
myString = myString.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?![a-z])/g, '');
console.log(myString);
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/aMU3fT/1)

Answer (score 0):

I use once replace to do this.

```
var myString = "     Hello  , how are         you   ?    ";
myString = myString.replace(/(\s+(?=[,\.?!])|^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s))/g, "")
console.log(myString);
//Expected output: "Hello, how are you?"
```

The code is combine several regex to be one regex. Because we want replace more space with "". To avoid unexpected output we need to do something with special case (with ",!?").

```
myString.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, ""); //same as
myString.trim();

myString.replace((\s+(?=[\.,!?])), "");
//Will only matches spaces (which following .,!?)
//So only spaces will be replace

myString.replace((\s+(?=\s)), "");
//same as with following ,.!? But this case with space

//see on the regex replaced with same that is "", so we can combine them together
myString.replace(/(\s+(?=[,\.?!])|^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s))/g, "")
```